# How do I find charging stations for an e-bike tour in France?

Tags: touring, charging

I have to travel to a village in the northern Vosges, and I want to go by train to somewhere close to the German-French border and do the last leg of the journey by e-bike. A convenient station would be Karlsruhe, but then I would have to cover 100 km by bicycle, which will bring my battery to its limits even if I restrict myself to the lowest assist level.

I tried using Google Maps to find public e-bike charging stations along the route, but it only showed some in Germany, and none in France.

It doesn't have to be some kind of outdoors charging tower, I would be OK with sitting down in a café to have lunch and taking the battery inside for charging, but I don't know how many owners would agree to that, especially with the current energy crisis in France.

Can I expect to find charging stations in that region? If yes, what resources exist to help me find them?

---

Update: I made the trip a few weeks ago. Since I couldn't locate potential charging points, I picked a different route and started in Wissembourg - a less convenient train connection, but only around 70 km of riding. The battery had sufficient capacity to do this in the lowest assist mode, with an overall speed of almost 13 km/h (there were hills a few unpaved stretches, though). Even finding an open café in the area proved difficult, so I didn't get to ask if they would let me top up the battery.

I cannot in good conscience accept an answer, because I cannot confirm that any of the suggested options work (maybe public charging isn't even possible currently in the region). It is possible that I will at some point repeat the route and have more luck, or maybe charging points will become more popular (and findable) in the future, so I am hopeful for more development someday.

Comment: I suggest (based on discussions in/about the UK, which is why this isn't an answer) looking for cycling-friendly *accommodation* providers, which are easier to find, and getting in touch. Not that you'd be staying, but a hotel that understands e-bikes and has a restaurant could be just what you need. But I reckon you'd probably be able to put a little bit of charge in at a coffee stop in a bar in France (maybe offering to pay, though I doubt you'd use more than €1 of electricity at any given stop.

Comment: Public e-bike chargers aren't really a thing except in very limited locations, so it might partly be that you're looking for the wrong thing - but we should be able to figure out the right thing

Comment: In some places, [Cafe Network](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1TF8mumGKoA9_kUhQVlaLaEswNBg&ll=48.827387770404854%2C7.512246493610495&z=12) can be a useful source of bike-friendly cafes that might be worth contacting.  While originally from the UK it extends further afield.  But there's nothing near your likely route until near the end

Comment: Depending on your level of fitness, it is possible to do a 100 km ride without a battery at all.  Will take 5 hours at 20 km/h, plus rest breaks.  You could just make a day of it and leave the battery for climbs or the last half of the ride.

Comment: @Criggie you are overestimating my speed a lot, I am hoping for a 20 km/h *with* assist (lowest level, else I won't get enough range from the battery), and 18 may be more realistic as a sustained average speed.

Answer (score 5):

Open Street Map (OSM) has tags for EBike charging points.

- amenity = charging_station
- bike = yes

Looks like this.

[image]

Depending on your dexterity with OSM you may like to use Komoot which uses OSM data and let’s you search directly for EBike charge points.

[image]

Your suggested start has a few nearby but seems to imply that while they are frequent in Germany, not so much in France.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how you got that search to work on Komoot - I've tried a few searches and can't get them to show up. Do you need premium mapping?  I've tried all the other options

Comment: You can also use overpass turbo to search OSM http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1n2u  Searching the whole of Europe returns a few clusters and a few odd ones in Germany and the Netherlands, one in each of France, the UK, Denmark, and Switzerland, and nothing anywhere else.

Comment: @ChrisH might be a paid thing. I have worldwide mapping paid for.

Comment: I've got worldwide mapping (it's my main route planner so I make good use of it) but since I got that they've added premium layers which I don't have. I much prefer the open cycle map layer anyway.

Comment: I tried looking around OSM, thanks. Surprisingly, I got different results from you, but again, very little in France. I am starting to wonder if this may be just a reflection of there being no data, as opposed to there being no opportunities to charge. Then again, maybe e-bikes are not as common in the deep rural regions of France as in the economically strong German south.

Comment: @rumtscho even looking at places where I know e-bikes themselves are common in France and the UK, public chargers aren't.  To a good approximation they don't exist outside Germany.  That's not to say you can't charge, but that there's nothing dedicated to it

Comment: @ChrisH I think that many of the charging points shown for Germany are not dedicated stations, but rather places which will let one top up. But I have to look into it. Maybe I'll try going to a few of the closer ones and see what they are like.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend finding a bike lane with lots of traffic, and calling the restaurants along this bike lane. Ebikes are pretty common these days, so it is likely they already had customers ask for this service. It should be easier if you make a reservation.

There is a [map of long distance bike routes](https://www.af3v.org/les-voies-vertes/carte-du-schema-national-des-veloroutes-et-voies-vertes/) which you might find useful, it looks like there are some along your planned trip.

Assuming a battery capacity of 250 Wh and a charger efficiency of 80% you're looking at only 0.3 kWh, so the energy crisis shouldn't be a factor. Worst case, you can always tip!

Comment: I know that the battery won't use up much electricity. I suspect that a random café owner won't know that, and that they will be simply disinclined to say "yes" to somebody carrying around a large battery and speaking bad french, in times when there is a huge feeling of scarcity and expense surrounding energy.

Comment: It's okay, you can tell him it uses as much electricity as the 3kW toaster oven running for only six minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Germany, I suggest you to have a look at this site:

https://www.bettundbike.de/en/

You may find accomodation with restaurants, then you just need to plan your 2-3 hours stop to happen there.

However, the easiest solution is to buy a second battery or rent it (in the sense of renting an e-bike having the same battery).

Two batteries are heavy, but marginally heavier for the complete system bicycle+cyclist, so you have the advantage you can use the double off the assist and find yourself at the exactly same point without charge ;)

Comment: Thank you, the map looks interesting for future trips. I asked for France, because I will only ride the first ~15 km in Germany. A second battery would be a great solution, and it would be awesome if somebody would rent me one, but I couldn't find such a service. Renting a whole bike for three days will cost more than 100 euro, and batteries for sale start at 400 euro for refurbished, so it is too expensive.

Comment: The battery is an energy carrier ... and also a money carrier: you can try your luck in buying a used one on a second hand site of your choice, and then resell it after the trip ;)